# Android upload file exception Invalid token character ' ' in token "json charset=UTF-8"

Tags: android, json, rest, upload, android-annotations

I am trying to send a POST request on web server with Android Annotations REST Api, and I am trying to send an image as a Base64 String and video as a file.
The operation also needs a Bearer Auth but I have managed that without an error.

My RestClient interface is like this:

```
@Rest(rootUrl = NetworkConstants.BASE_URL, converters = {GsonHttpMessageConverter.class, StringHttpMessageConverter.class, 
    FormHttpMessageConverter.class},interceptors = {
HeadersRequestInterceptor.class })
public interface RestClient extends RestClientHeaders {

@Post(NetworkConstants.UPLOAD_URL)
VideoUploadResponse uploadVideo(MultiValueMap<String,Object> model);

}
```

And my Request is like this:

```
 MultiValueMap dataMultiPart = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    File file = new File(path);
    dataMultiPart.add("thumbnail", bitmapString);
    dataMultiPart.add("media", new FileSystemResource(file));
    try {
        VideoUploadResponse resonse = restClient.uploadVideo(dataMultiPart);

    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

In my interceptor class I have tried both this

```
public class HeadersRequestInterceptor implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor {
@Override
public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request, byte[] body, ClientHttpRequestExecution execution) throws IOException {
    request.getHeaders().add("content-type", MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE);
    request.getHeaders().add("authorization", "Bearer sometokenvalue");
    return execution.execute(request, body);
}
}
```

and this

```
public class HeadersRequestInterceptor implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor {
@Override
public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request, byte[] body, ClientHttpRequestExecution execution) throws IOException {
    request.getHeaders().setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
    request.getHeaders().add("authorization", "Bearer sometokenvalue");
    return execution.execute(request, body);
}
}
```

And I am getting the exception Invalid token character ' ' in token "json charset=UTF-8" everytime.

At first I thought there might be a problem with the auth token, but there is not.And when I try this request with postman there is no such error.

[Postman Request Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzngB.png)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved in several ways:

```
@Rest(rootUrl = rootUrl = NetworkConstants.BASE_UR, converters = FormHttpMessageConverter.class, interceptors = HeadersRequestInterceptor.class)
public interface RestClient extends RestClientHeaders {

      @Post(NetworkConstants.UPLOAD_URL)
      @RequiresHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE)  
      VideoUploadResponse uploadVideo(@Path int id, @Body MultiValueMap<String, Object> data);     
}

MultiValueMap dataMultiPart = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
File file = new File(path);
dataMultiPart.add("thumbnail", bitmapString);
dataMultiPart.add("media", new FileSystemResource(file));
try {

   restClient.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE);
   VideoUploadResponse resonse = restClient.uploadVideo(dataMultiPart);

} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

It is even easier in AA 4.0:

```
@Rest(rootUrl = rootUrl = NetworkConstants.BASE_UR, converters = FormHttpMessageConverter.class, interceptors = HeadersRequestInterceptor.class)
public interface RestClient extends RestClientHeaders {

  @Post(NetworkConstants.UPLOAD_URL)
  VideoUploadResponse uploadVideo(@Part String thumbnail, @Part FileSystemResource media);
}

restClient.uploadVideo(bitmapString, new FileSystemResource(file));
```

Comment: Hello, I have tried these exactly the same way, the result is the same.Also when I try to add @RequiresHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE)  on top of my request function in my RestClient I got an error "CONTENT_TYPE has private access in HttpHeaders"

Comment: Sorry, i was using Spring Android RestTemplate 2.0, where those constants are public. But you can just add `"Content-Type"`.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out problem was not because of me, but the server side.

Server is sending "application/json charset=UTF-8" as Content-Type, but Spring framework is strict in parsing headers, and it sees the space character between "json" and "charset" as an error.Normally it should be "application","json;charset=utf-8”;

That's why problem was happening while using Android Annotations or Retrofit.

It was working well with Postman because it is less strict in parsing headers.

I am using now Google Volley for network communication and the problem is gone.